# Generic parameter 'Result' could not be inferred with RxSwift

Tags: swift, closures, rx-swift

I am new to Swift, so maybe the question is a little bit stupid. I don't know why I got the error here:

```
htmlHelper.fetchHtmlObservable(url) // this one is an Observable<String> function
            .subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler.init(qos: .background))
            .map { //Generic parameter 'Result' could not be inferred
                let parsingHelper = ParsingTypeFactory.getParsingType(parsingType: self.parsingType)
                return parsingHelper.parseActionItems(document: $0)
            }
```

To resolve it, I had to add

```
.map { doc -> [MyItem] in
     let parsingHelper = ParsingTypeFactory.getParsingType(parsingType: self.parsingType)
     return parsingHelper.parseActionItems(document: doc)
}
```

When can I omit the `params` and the `return` type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for type inference to work in closures, you generally need either the outer scope to know the type or the closure itself needs to be one line. This is a limitation in the Swift type system. So either:

```swift
htmlHelper.fetchHtmlObservable(url) // this one is an Observable<String> function
    .subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler.init(qos: .background))
    .map {
        ParsingTypeFactory.getParsingType(parsingType: self.parsingType).parseActionItems(document: $0)
    }
```

or

```swift
let myItems: Observable<[MyItem]> = htmlHelper.fetchHtmlObservable(url) // this one is an Observable<String> function
    .subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler.init(qos: .background))
    .map {
        let parsingHelper = ParsingTypeFactory.getParsingType(parsingType: self.parsingType)
        return parsingHelper.parseActionItems(document: $0)
    }
```

### Other options:

Note that in all of the cases discussed so far, you are holding a strong reference to self and likely causing a memory cycle/leak. You can avoid that by making a helper function that isn't part of the class:

```swift
// do NOT put this in the class, make it a free function (possibly private to avoid namespace pollution.)
func parser(for parsingType: ParsingType) -> (Document) -> [MyItem] {
    return { document in
        let parsingHelper = ParsingTypeFactory.getParsingType(parsingType: parsingType)
        return parsingHelper.parseActionItems(document: document)
    }
}
```

And now the code in question becomes:

```swift
let myItems = htmlHelper.fetchHtmlObservable(url) // this one is an Observable<String> function
    .subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler.init(qos: .background))
    .map(parser(for: parsingType))
```

---

If you don't like the idea of a free function, or you don't like a function that returns a function, you can put the function in an extension on ParserType:

```swift
extension ParsingType {
    func parser(document: Document) -> [MyItem] {
        let parsingHelper = ParsingTypeFactory.getParsingType(parsingType: self)
        return parsingHelper.parseActionItems(document: document)
    }
}
```

and now the original code becomes:

```swift
let myItems = htmlHelper.fetchHtmlObservable(url) // this one is an Observable<String> function
    .subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler.init(qos: .background))
    .map(parsingType.parser(document:))
```

This also avoids keeping a reference to self.

Comment: Thanks. IMO, 1 line map function is really hard to read. Declaring the type here `Observable<[MyItem]>` is not really helpful especially in map function as you can add more map functions in the future. As a result, I keep using this: `doc -> [MyItem] in`.

Comment: I prefer the `(doc) -> [MyItem] in` version as well. Either that or I make a helper function that contains the multiple lines. I will add an example in the answer.

Comment: This was REALLY helpful. I had no idea you could solve type inference issues with storing the observable in a variable or having the closure in one line. Strange, but both ways worked. Many thanks!